# Does ordering of validate and flush in Grails save method Matters?

Tags: grails

I want to understand that ordering of Flush and Validate in Grails save method matters?

I have code snippet as : entity.save(flush: true, validate: false) and entity.save(validate: false, flush: true) in which first one is not saving any data but the later one is updating the database table.

Can someone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 1):

Not it does not.  This syntax is shorthand for `...save({validate:false, ...})`.  So this passes a map to that function.  Maps are not ordered/sorted (well the map literal in groovy actually creates an ordered one for you, but that does not matter).

The order of validate and flush is defined in the code handling the save function. See [`GormInstanceApi.doSave`](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/GormInstanceApi.groovy#L315).